# PDDL error compiling

Tags: compilation, pddl

I am new to PDDL, i have been trying a blocksworld problem but i got the error:

> Failed to parse the problem -- Not args must be a list with only one element, got [Primitive sobre (default_object ?obj, default_object ?obj2), Primitive libre (default_object ?obj3), Primitive en (default_object ?obj, default_object ?from)]
>   /tmp/solver_planning_domains_tmp_4BmsZdP37zJXS/domain.pddl: syntax error in line 16, '(':
>   domain definition expected

my files are these:

```
(define (domain blocly)
   (:predicates (espacio ?e)  
        (ficha ?t)  
        (sobre ?t ?t)  
        (en ?t ?e)  
        (vacio ?e)  
        (libre ?t))  


    (:action movefichaficha
       :parameters (?ficha ?ficha2 ?ficha3 ?from ?to)
       :precondition (and  (ficha ?ficha) (ficha ?ficha2) (ficha ?ficha3) (espacio ?from) (espacio ?to)
                     (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2) (libre ?ficha) (libre ?ficha3) (en ?ficha ?from) (en ?ficha2 ?from) 
                     (en ?ficha3 ?to))
       :effect (and (sobre ?ficha ?ficha3) (en ?ficha ?to) (libre ?ficha2)
               (not (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2) (libre ?ficha3) (en ?ficha ?from)))) 

    (:action movefichaesp
       :parameters (?ficha ?ficha2 ?from ?to)
       :precondition (and  (ficha ?ficha) (ficha ?ficha2) (espacio ?from) (espacio ?to)
                     (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2) (vacio ?to) (en ?ficha ?from) (en ?ficha2 ?from))
       :effect (and  (libre ?ficha2) (en ?ficha ?to) (arriba ?ficha ?to)
               (not (vacio ?to) (en ?ficha ?from) (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2))))

    (:action moveoespficha
       :parameters  (?ficha ?ficha2 ?from ?to)
       :precondition (and  (ficha ?ficha) (ficha ?ficha2) (espacio ?from) (espacio ?to)
                     (libre ?ficha) (libre ?ficha2) (en ?ficha ?from) (en ?ficha ?to) ())
       :effect (and  (vacio ?from) (en ?ficha ?to) (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2)
             (not (libre ?ficha2) (en ?ficha ?from) (en ?ficha ?from)))))
```

and these:

```
(define (problem blockly-world)  
   (:domain blocly)  
   (:objects t1 t2 t3 e1 e2 e3)  
   (:init (ficha t1)   
          (ficha t2)  
          (ficha t3)  
          (espacio e1)  
          (espacio e2)  
          (espacio e3)  
          (sobre t3 t2)  
          (sobre t2 t1)  
          (en t1 e1)  
          (en t2 e1)  
          (en t3 e1)  
          (libre t3)  
          (vacio e2)  
          (vacio e3))  
   (:goal (and (sobre t1 t2)  
               (sobre t2 t3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems in the source code.

- The *problem file* lacks a final `)`
- The **unary** `not` logical operator is used improperly, e.g.

  ```
  (not (vacio ?to) (en ?ficha ?from) (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2))
  ```

  should be rewritten as

  ```
  (not (vacio ?to))
  (not (en ?ficha ?from))
  (not (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2))
  ```
- The *domain file* uses an **undeclared** predicate, `arriba`. Since it has the same definition of `en` --and it is not mentioned in the `(:init ...)` block--, I am unsure whether this is a typo due to renaming `arriba` into `en` and forgetting to change one last occurrence of it, or not. Just in case it is not an error, you can fix it by adding

  ```
   (arriba ?t ?e)
  ```

  to the list of predicates. You should check on you own whether you need to add something to the `(:init ...)` block in the *problem file* or not.

---

Below, you can find a *properly indented* version of the source code with adequate fixes to the first two identified issues, and an attempt to solve the third issue:

**blocky-prob.pddl:**

```
(define (problem blockly-world)  
    (:domain blocly)  
    (:objects t1 t2 t3 e1 e2 e3)  
    (:init
          (ficha t1)   
          (ficha t2)  
          (ficha t3)  
          (espacio e1)  
          (espacio e2)  
          (espacio e3)  
          (sobre t3 t2)  
          (sobre t2 t1)  
          (en t1 e1)  
          (en t2 e1)  
          (en t3 e1)  
          (libre t3)  
          (vacio e2)  
          (vacio e3)
    )  
   (:goal (and
              (sobre t1 t2)
              (sobre t2 t3)
          )
   )
)
```

**block-domain.pddl:**

```
(define (domain blocly)
    (:predicates
        (espacio ?e)  
        (ficha ?t)  
        (sobre ?t ?t)  
        (en ?t ?e)
        (arriba ?t ?e)
        (vacio ?e)  
        (libre ?t)
    )  

    (:action movefichaficha
        :parameters (?ficha ?ficha2 ?ficha3 ?from ?to)
        :precondition
            (and
                (ficha ?ficha)
                (ficha ?ficha2)
                (ficha ?ficha3)
                (espacio ?from)
                (espacio ?to)
                (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2)
                (libre ?ficha)
                (libre ?ficha3)
                (en ?ficha ?from)
                (en ?ficha2 ?from) 
                (en ?ficha3 ?to)
            )
        :effect
            (and
                (sobre ?ficha ?ficha3)
                (en ?ficha ?to)
                (libre ?ficha2)
                (not (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2))
                (not (libre ?ficha3))
                (not (en ?ficha ?from))
            )
    )

    (:action movefichaesp
        :parameters (?ficha ?ficha2 ?from ?to)
        :precondition
            (and
                (ficha ?ficha)
                (ficha ?ficha2)
                (espacio ?from)
                (espacio ?to)
                (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2)
                (vacio ?to)
                (en ?ficha ?from)
                (en ?ficha2 ?from)
            )
        :effect
            (and
                (libre ?ficha2)
                (en ?ficha ?to)
                (arriba ?ficha ?to)
                (not (vacio ?to))
                (not (en ?ficha ?from))
                (not (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2))
            )
    )

    (:action moveoespficha
        :parameters  (?ficha ?ficha2 ?from ?to)
        :precondition
            (and
                (ficha ?ficha)
                (ficha ?ficha2)
                (espacio ?from)
                (espacio ?to)
                (libre ?ficha)
                (libre ?ficha2)
                (en ?ficha ?from)
                (en ?ficha ?to) 
            )
        :effect
            (and
                (vacio ?from)
                (en ?ficha ?to)
                (sobre ?ficha ?ficha2)
                (not (libre ?ficha2))
                (not (en ?ficha ?from))
                (not (en ?ficha ?from))
            )
    )
)
```

The code is properly *parsed* by the *PDDL* solver **fast-downward.py** on my machine, which also finds a solution. Since I don't know what you are trying to model, I am unable to verify whether it matches what you want to model or not.

---

**Notes:** even if you are just learning for personal reasons, consider getting in the habit of using *english* names for your predicates, objects and variables. Moreover, consider that indenting the source code and properly describing the situation you are dealing with has the double benefit of attracting both upvotes and good answers to your questions.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try it out when I get home. Sorry for the newbie mistakes. I'll make sure to learn from this :)